# 'Free hat for a quick chat' Friday!

Tags: discussion, chat, winter-bash

..and Thursday apparently!

> ***If your head is cold, or you just like a freebie, head on over to chat now!***

We're slacking behind on the [Winter Bash leaderboard](http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com/leaderboard)! There's a hat that can only be awarded for a limited time today in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1240/the-ink-spot), come in and say hello to get it!

There's also a secret hat that can be earned on meta by posting a few comments that receive a bunch of upvotes (allegedly :P)...

Comment: If we all just post comments and spread the holiday cheer, we can all get hats ;)

Comment: Hat Hat Hat!!!!

Comment: I believe in unicorns.

Comment: I think it might require multiple comments

Comment: No, you require multiple comments!

Comment: Right, you might be, young skywalker!

Comment: we should ban scott from hats..  j/k

Comment: anyone got a new head-warmer yet?

Comment: Why do I need to be banned from hats? That's just mean. Flagged Matt. :)

Comment: We should upgrade Matt to `3.0`. ;)

Comment: beta 3.0 matt would work

Comment: Do you come with new features?

Comment: Chapeau chapeau unicorn!

Comment: @Dominic well... that what she said...  if that helps ;)

Comment: please take this to chat..

Comment: So how many of you got the unicorn hat??

Comment: @ckpepper02 I got one!

Comment: Is it five upvotes that are required?

Comment: @Red the speculation is that you need at least 5 comments that receive upvotes on meta. Serious comments only (as exemplified by the other comments in this post)!!

Comment: I'm back! Can't believe I missed the chance to get a unicorn hat! Help, HELP!!

Comment: i NEED a unicorn hat.... NEED.

Answer (score 3):

We definitely want to get our place up on the leader board.

Unicorns are cool, comment if you agree..

[image: unicorn][image: johnbsunicorn]

reference "[Has anyone on EL&U been awarded the 'I See Your Point' hat yet?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4338/has-anyone-on-elu-been-awarded-the-i-see-your-point-hat-yet)" if you are wondering where this started.

Comment: Looks a bit like a donkey..?

Comment: Is this like a critique post? I think the eyes are too saturated, it clashes too sharply with the rest of the image. I would bring down the saturation just a tiny bit so that they blend well with the pastel tones of the background.

Comment: I like the way the eyes glare at you when you cover up the nose and mouth. It creates a great contrast with the soft teletubby background.

Comment: Oh teletubbies, unicorns, skittles & lucky charms! What a wonderful Utopia!

Comment: I once saw that unicorn on a trip through Denver. Darn thing almost ate my left arm. Scariest merry-g-round ever.

Comment: My take on it: http://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Are.jpg

Comment: whats up with the pixelation?

Comment: is pixelating images in GD scope?

Comment: I think we have too much free time today..

Comment: Throw some wings on it and make it a pegasus.

Comment: You cannot possibly have too much free time. That's like having too much RAM or too large a hard drive

Comment: @Lauren like this? http://i.imgur.com/oPoojxi.jpg

Comment: If the system can't support that amount of RAM, it would be too much

Comment: MOAR RAM DAGNABBIT

Comment: I think Lauren was talking about the new Daft Punk album

Comment: And more unicorns! UniRAM?

Comment: @JohnB Is it any good? I really liked "Technologic" but I haven't gotten around to getting a full album.

Comment: My name is Giorgio, everyone calls me Georgie

Comment: @LaurenIpsum its terrific! One of the best albums I've ever heard

Comment: @Lauren I love it, if you're into disco with an electronic twist then you'll probably enjoy it

Comment: ... Lot of extended comments, perhaps we should take this to chat :X

Comment: Ciao Giorgio! :)

Comment: @LaurenIpsum http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LrlxbIgzTHI

Comment: @Ryan Grazie! will bookmark to watch later. And listen, technically.

Comment: Fa'afetai lava. (My italian is rusty so I'll bust out the samoan)

Comment: Falafel in the volcano? I don't speak Samoan at all.

Comment: Fa'afetai = Thank you. Fa'afetai lava = You're welcome. Malo Tiene pronounced Malo Kiene = Heeeyy Girl

Comment: please take this to chat..

Comment: Who got the bloomin hat??

Comment: I hope this comment is used for awesome.

Comment: Spam Spam Comments Beans and Spam

Comment: @RedSirius or Lobster Thermidor à Crevette with a mornay sauce served in a Provençale manner with shallots and aubergines garnished with truffle pâté, brandy and with a fried egg on top and comments and spam.

Comment: I want a unicorn hat! :D

Comment: I love the point you made about Unicorns!